# how deploy OSGi bundles in correct order in JBoss

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, osgi, jboss7.x

I try to understand how to work with OSGi and JBoss AS

I try to deploy tree bundles: b1, b2. b3.
I copied bundles directory **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments**.
Then I started JBoss. Bundles deployed in incorrect order.
As I understood I should make profile for this. But I cannot understand how to write it. Now I think the I should modify file **standalone.xml** and add description of my bundles.

Could you help me with correct deploying of bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need bundle starting order because of service dependencies between bundles b1, b2 and b3. In OSGi, to manage service dependencies, you can use [Dynamic Services](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t91059.rhtml) or [Declarative Services](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t96740.html). Hope this might help you.